# How to deal with number of pageviews in RESTful calls?

Tags: http, rest, get

I'd like to have a request returning some "analytics" as part of the request: most importantly, I'd like *every* GET requests to return the number of times the GET request has been called.

Is this fundamentally incompatible with the RESTful concept?

If it's not fundamentally incompatible, how can I have my RESTful server return a different result for each GET request seen that, by definition of this problem, every GET requests means the next GET request must return something different?

If it's fundamentally impossible to do in a RESTful way, should I drop REST or do I drop GET altogether?

*P.S: This is my first question on SO so apparently I won't be able to comment unless I hit 15 rep so it would be nice if commenters/answerers could upvote me so that I can be part of the SO community : )*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no incompatibility with REST in principle here. You should *consider* the effect that a constantly-changing resource will not benefit from caching (assuming you don't want the visit count to go stale). You should also consider that number to be constantly "eventually consistent"; that is, it will represent the count for some subset of the requests if you have lots executing in parallel. And you should also consider returning the count in an "X-Visit-Count" header instead of the main payload to make the feature more generic and avoid polluting whatever payload you do return, and potentially allow for better caching. But there's nothing at all "against REST" for a resource to return a different representation each time you GET it.

Comment: damn, I don't get it (pun intended ; )   I had the impression that REST meant that GET requests were idempotent.  How would I go about being "eventually consistent"?  By setting an expiration time in the reply?  So that I'd get best of both worlds: still allow caching and yet be eventually consistent?  Besides that, I don't know how "polluting" such a counter would be: most websites nowadays (StackOverflow, Google+, FaceBook and basically all the forums) do clearly display how many pageviews there have been.  This has become an inherent part of many websites.

Comment: The idempotency is only relevant from the POV of the caller. If the server changes something then that is the server's responsibility. From a client POV, there must not be a difference betwen 1 GET and 1000 GETs. IOW, if the caller *intends* the change - use POST.

Comment: @Jan Algermissen: that is very interesting... In a case like, say, StackOverflow, where a GET (I presume) can trigger a *"viewed 9 times"* to be transformed to a *"viewed 10 times"*, do you consider the caller intended or not the change?

Comment: The caller intends to view the page. If you develop a bot to hit the site to increase the counter, I'd consider that an abuse of discovered server behavior. Also: the server can implement techniques to make the view count more accurate (protect against counting multiple immediate views by same client for example) without impactiing the intended result.

Comment: @Jan Algermissen: First I never talked about bots ; )   Then I don't 100% agree with *"The caller intends to view the page."*.  The fact is that *"The caller intends to view the page and that page shows a counter telling how many times the page has been seen and the caller expect to see that counter"*: that is how SO and most forums work: they do show a counter and that counter convey a very useful information.  So... Does the caller intend the change or not in such a case?

Comment: As I said: If you hit reload 100 times and the counter does not change - do you say: "SO is crappy" or do you say "Ah, see - they protected themselves against that"? The GET is still idenpotent. The display of the view count is just part of the resource semantics. The counter increment is not part of the user intention. Otherwise SO should have used POST. Beyond that, its a philosophical problem.

Comment: @Jan Algermissen: I think you misunderstood what I meant.  I'm not talking about the counter for that user to be incremented every time that particular user does the same GET.  I'm talking about the number of page views, as seen by **another user** being incremented.  Put it this way: *user A does a GET* (he sees "nb pageview 8") then *user B does a GET* (he sees "nb pageview 9") then *user A does the same GET* again (he sees "nb pageview 10" -- that's how it works on SO btw).  I don't see how the call is idempotent here and nobody is trying to "game" anything nor to "cheat".

Comment: Doesn't matter. The issue is whether or not the client intended, and therefore should be held responsible for, the changes. For most site counters, the client should not. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-16#section-7.1